# Disable sound from a Windows application

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11

Is there a way to disable all sound from an `.exe`, or preferably just Windows error sounds, if it **does not show up in volume mixer**? (Without wiping the sound file or other undesired effects)

---

**Details**: MATLAB makes the standard Windows error sound upon an invalid text manipulation (e.g. pressing arrow down in empty console). It also beeps for other things - they're handled by its built-in command [`beep off`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/beep.html), but it's not universal.

Answer (score 1):

As MATLAB does not show up in volume mixer, then it's not using
the speakers as an audio device, but is issuing a system sound.

Unfortunately, system sounds are generated by calling a Windows API
which cannot be blocked, unless you change or remove the beep sound for
the entire Windows in *Control Panel > Sounds > Sounds tab*.

You need to find some setting in MATLAB to do it correctly.
Otherwise, the only solution is to specify the sound for the MATLAB
application in the registry.

The registry key in question is
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps`, under which can be specified
overrides for system sounds for some applications.
You see the same in *Control Panel > Sounds > Sound tab*.

For example, you will see this in the Sounds applet :

[image]

While in the registry you will see this :

[image]

The way then to stop MATLAB from issuing the beep sound is:

- Use the Sounds applet to identify the exact system sound that
  MATLAB issues as beep using the Test button
- Verify the name of the sound under registry key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default`
  which contains the Windows default sound. Usually this will be
  the same as you see in the Sounds applet without blank separators.
  Below I'll use for it the arbitrary name of `systembeep`
  (not the real name).
- Verify this by changing in the Sounds applet the value of this sound
  to `(None)`. Remember and rest the old value.
- Use the `.exe` name if MATLAB, let's say `matlab.exe`,
  to create the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\matlab\systembeep`
- Under this key create two sub-keys named `.Current` and
  `.Default` with no value for the item `(Default)`

If all went well, the beep sound will now be silenced for MATLAB.

Useful article :
[Change System Sounds in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-system-sounds-in-windows-11.9937/#Three).

Comment: Some notes: 1) One sound file may be used for more than one sound, so this might not be (only) "System Notification", 2) The name of the sound would correctly be `SystemNotification`, the trick is that every upper-case letter starts a new word when displayed, (3) I would used [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace MATLAB and find what exactly it's doing, but that is advanced stuff.

Comment: There are many possibilities : MATLAB can be using a system sound, using a system file directly, using a sound resource inside its `.exe`, or manufacturing a sound via API. You can check all the `.wav` files in `C:\Windows\Media`. Using Process Monitor might be faster, to trace MATLAB when issuing the beep (you don't have to trace its startup) and you should set up a filter for `matlab.exe` (or whatever). If you aren't sure, export the log to a file, zip it and post online.

Comment: [Tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBz4G.png), also restarted PC... is there still a point to trying the Process Monitor route if we know it works to set `Default Beep` to `(None)`? (+1 I trust your method works in general and I learned a good deal)

Comment: Setting Default Beep to `(None)` will do it for all programs. As this is a registry item, you could perhaps start MATLAB via a `.bat` file that will set the Default Beep and launch MATLAB. Another `.bat` file could restore the default (or even a `.reg` file that you could generate by Export from regedit).

Comment: I wonder if in addition to `.Current` and `.Default` you should have `.Modified` with the same value.

Comment: Tried, also tried `.Default` instead of `DefaultBeep`. I wonder if it's about `Type` = `REG_EXPAND_SZ` for `.Default` and that it uses `%SystemRoot` in `Data`, but I don't know how to change `Type`? (no google results either) -- [Cleaned up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoEAF.png) my comments, storing them here.

Comment: Eh, I have doubts. To my mind, if this method generally works, I really can't think of why it'd fail here. It being some esoteric edge case is fair game, but could you comment on what's up? I'm open to accepting even if the problem isn't solved -- I'll get back to this tomorrow.

Comment: You could try `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Matlab\.Default\.Current`. But if this doesn't work, then no problem.

Comment: My search suggests the registry keys are case-insensitive (also, didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

To disable (or change) *all* error sounds, just [change System Sounds](https://www.lifewire.com/change-windows-10-system-sounds-4587694). While this won't distinguish MATLAB sounds from Windows defaults, it can make them more pleasant. You can make *separate* sound schemes for running MATLAB and for other uses. You can also [make .reg files](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/285-sounds-change.html) to switch sound  schemes quickly with a keyboard shortcut.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `system sounds` and select *Change system sounds*.
- Pick the sound you want to change, e.g., *Critical Stop*.
- Press *Test* to confirm it's the one that needs to be changed.
- Find or create a .wav sound file to substitute. You can use a tool such as [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/) to clip, modify and save a short sound in .wav format. Set the volume to zero to make it silent, or perhaps use a low volume setting so you get *some* less obtrusive feedback.
- Save the scheme with a name, if you wish.
- Press *OK* to keep settings.

[image: System Sounds]

Comment: The problem is that for anything other than MATLAB I _want_ it to stay intrusive - anyway good info, thanks