# Where is Default Beep in Windows registry?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11

`System Notification` is found in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemNotification`, and so are many other options that are listed under `Control Panel > Sound > Sounds`.

But where's `Default Beep`? I used `Edit > Find` with `DefaultBeep` (I have a very fast CPU and 32GB RAM) and it slows down my entire laptop and turns up nothing in 3 minutes. A result quickly shows for `default beep`, but it's obscure and not what I'm looking for (also tried `Find Next` with `default beep` but again no timely results):

[image]

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-system-beep-windows-7-8 Why do you want to find that? Do you just want to disable the "beep"? Do you want to know the location of the file? What is your goal?

Comment: The is to learn how the entry is structured so I can replicate it on a per-application basis to disable it for the application, as outlined [here](https://superuser.com/a/1804068/1010638) (in case it's not exactly as outlined there).

Comment: I doubt that what you're looking for exists.

Comment: It seems to be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current` with value `C:\WINDOWS\media\Windows Background.wav`.

Comment: Gotta be kidding me... so MATLAB chose the one key that appears to have exceptional handling. Well if you're sure I guess that's the answer... but I'll keep looking @harrymc

Comment: @harrymc Confirmed by changing `.Current`'s `Data` to something else and testing in MATLAB, feel free to post as answer. (also didn't need to restart MATLAB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default Beep is in registry key :
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current`.

Its value is set to `C:\WINDOWS\media\Windows Background.wav`.

Comment: But how would you set that as a per-application setting for MATLAB?

Comment: Possibly as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Matlab\.Default\.Current`. If it doesn't work, this is a mystery. There is not documentation about it and much of my two answers was my own analysis.

Comment: Thanks again for all the back & forth - this isn't the only thing broke in MATLAB.